# I have a 6 year old Hp Desktop.. trying to restore it but wont go?

Tags: windows-xp, boot, bios

Iam trying to restore a Hp computer with xp. I put the disk in and it just wants to go to f12 or f2. then the blue screen comes up and say its restarting and just starts over. It wont let me push the f8 safe mode. Is there any other way to just take it all the way down and let it run the restore the disk?   It seems like its trying keep going to the f12 or f2 keys? any help?

Comment: Silly question.  As old as this laptop is, how dirty is your keyboard?  Are the F12 or F2 keys stuck?

Answer (score 1):

First be sure that is no hardware problem. It is possible to be an faulty ram or psu or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set your BIOS it sounds like to boot from the CD-Rom drive first. This can be done by changing what's usually called "boot order" or something similar. Change the boot order to look for your CD-ROM drive first and it should boot from your restore disk.

Comment: I should add that you'll need to press whatever button it tells you to enter the BIOS settings before you'll be able to find boot order.

Answer (score 0):

From another computer, download and burn a "live" CD of Linux and try to boot off that CD. If you still have problem booting, then it is your hardware. If you can boot without any problem,  then the problem is in your XP CD. May be it is time to switch you Linux :-)